# Trouble installing WiFi Driver in Kali Linux 2.0 rolling

Tags: linux, kali-linux, dkms

I am facing issues installing the driver from https://github.com/pvaret/rtl8192cu-fixes for tp-link wn823n 300Mpbs wireless adapter (this adapter supports only upto kernel version 2.10 while I have kernel version 4.3.0-kali1-amd64).

When I execute the below command which is from the driver instructions

```
sudo apt-get install git linux-headers-generic build-essential dkms
```

It gives me the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package linux-headers-generic is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'linux-headers-generic' has no installation candidate
```

Please help me solve the issue, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: There was no kernel version 2.10; version 2.1 was obsoleted in the 90s.

Comment: My bad!!! it supports (kernel versions 2.6.18 ~ 3.10.10)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think the driver for this wificard can be installed by adding hanipouspilot ppa this worked for me you can copy paste these commands .

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
sudo apt update
sudo apt install rtl8192eu-dkms
```

You can also try updating linux headers to latest kernel

[Install new headers to kali linux](https://infosechacker.com/blog/2016/04/08/how-to-install-linux-header-4-4-in-kali-rolling-2016/)

Comment: Buddy it gives me the error "E: Unable to locate package rtl8192eu-dkms
"

Comment: ok download it first and then try to installing it with dpkg -i command https://launchpad.net/~hanipouspilot/+archive/ubuntu/rtlwifi

Comment: also did you add the repository first ??

Comment: Yes i added! as per https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?3978-How-to-add-PPA-in-kali!!!!!!!

Comment: try downloading it manually then and let me know

Comment: I am done installing the hanipousploit rtl8192eu-dkms_4.4_all.deb  guess i have to restart!! or do i have to do something else!

Comment: let me know if it worked after restarting

Comment: It isnt working after restarting!!! I loaded the compat files and it shows the interface but it does not work!!!

Comment: Could you please post a link where I can find detailed procedure of solving the issue! I feel like I am missing some steps!

Comment: [link](https://github.com/Mange/rtl8192eu-linux-driver) i think you can compile it form source by cloning this repository

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy!!! I am very grateful for all your help,i had to update linux headers(and i did it as per https://infosechacker.com/blog/2016/04/08/how-to-install-linux-header-4-4-in-kali-rolling-2016/).....would you help me understanding the internal workings of linux!

Comment: your welcome, this is the sole purpose of these wonderful communities